# My question was closed because it "needs to be more focused", but it seems like a question many programmers would want to know the answer to

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, needs-more-focus

In anyway. Here is what I would say to you.

Recently, I had a very good question that you deemed "Not focused enough." I don't remember my question exactly since I have no access to it. It was something like this:
"How can I prevent access to a subdomain in flat HTML from a WordPress site?"

First of all, that was very focused. I'm sure many programmers/webmasters would like to know the answer to that.

Now, I found the perfect answer/solution.
But I am not going to share it, since you deleted it.

Comment: You can find your _recently_ deleted questions at the bottom of the [Questions tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=questions) on your profile. If you need to find one that wasn't deleted recently, you may raise a custom flag on any of your other posts and ask the moderator to find it for you. Or you can wait until a mod stumbles upon this post and help you. **Edit:** Aaaand Cody already came to the rescue :)

Comment: They asked to ["talk directly with \[a\] moderator"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/413061/revisions). I am not one to disappoint!

Comment: "But I ain't gonna share it, since you deleted it." - You actually deleted the question.  You decided, instead of editing the question and addressing the reason the question was closed, to simply delete the question.

Comment: Side note about deleted questions: They are still used in the top secret question ban algorithm. Usually if you're new you're better attempting to salvage the question than you are deleting it because a salvaged question can be upvoted. A deleted question just serves as a boat anchor.

Answer (score 35):

You posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69787259/how-to-limit-access-to-a-sub-domain-from-a-wordpress-domain) on October 31, 2021 at 13:16Z. The question was closed by votes from 3 community members on November 2, 2021 at 8:42Z. Finally, *you* deleted the question on November 2, 2021 at 10:23Z.

At no point in the process was a moderator ever involved. You can tell a moderator because their user name has a diamond following it, like this: ♦. On Meta sites, like this one, moderators also have a gratuitously ugly blue "Mod" box appended to their user names.

You seem to be arguing that the question is focused because "many programmers/webmasters would like to know the answer to that", but that does not make a question focused. That just makes it popular. There are plenty of other questions that programmers/webmasters would like to know the answer to, but they are not all on-topic for Stack Overflow.

Although I am a moderator, my programming speciality does not include either PHP or Wordpress, so I am not qualified to judge whether or not your question is focused enough to be suitable for our Q&A format.

However, it seems to be too late now. If you wanted to get the question re-opened, then you should not have deleted it. We wouldn't re-open a question that had been deleted.

Comment: Now, I want to give you another upvote for _'gratuitously ugly blue "Mod" box'_ :-D

Comment: Oh, I found my original question.
Thanks, that helps. Although, I'm still perplex as what makes the question focus more? I thought the topic was very clear. As clear as it can be when you have no clues. I usually come here to get a clue so I can build whatever I'm working on. 

At the time it offers me to make question 'more focus' or delete it. So I didn't know how to do the first one... Even now that I have the answer. I still don't know how to make the question more focus.

Comment: Are you sure we cannot reopen questions that are deleted? Or do we just don't want to?

Comment: @Dharman Yeah, technically you can vote to reopen a deleted question. It's... a weird UI bug.

Comment: -1, the blue box looks nice. (Didn’t actually downvote though).

Answer (score 10):

From comments under the existing answer:

> I'm still perplex as what makes a question focus? I thought the topic was very clear.

"Focussed" in this case doesn't just mean "clear", it means that the *scope* of the question is small enough. The statement "I want to build a self-driving car" is *clear*, but it's not *focussed* - there are years of research and development involved. Adding some detail of what you know isn't necessarily enough either - "I want to build a self-driving car, and I've worked out how to control a webcam using Python" still leaves 99% of the problem still to go.

Your question is obviously not as complex as a self-driving car, but it still has a lot of parts to design: how are users identified, how are purchases recorded, how is the purchased content displayed, and so on.

> As clear as it can be when you have no clue.

This is a common frustration - in order to write a good focussed question, you need to already know enough about the solution to break it apart. When you have no idea where to start, the strict Q&A format of this site just doesn't work - you'll want to have a discussion about what to learn, find off-site tutorials, get advice tailored to you personally.

It's really important to remember that the close vote isn't a judgement on you personally, or saying you're wrong to want help. It's just saying that this site isn't the right place to get that particular help.

Hopefully, you'll find information somewhere else that lets you start planning and implementing something. Then, you'll get stuck on some detail, and come back here with the kind of "focussed" question this site specialises in answering.

Comment: Thanks, I understand the focus thing now. 
BTW: I'm not asking you to write the code for me.  All I needed in my original question was to be pointed in the right direction.

A simple : You should look in the Hook functions in WordPress would have done the job for me.